# Can't load data from RestApi into RecyclerView using Retrofit:RecyclerView is always empty

Tags: android-recyclerview, linked-list, gson, retrofit, picasso

#### The RestApi used is jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. Below is the class corresponding to the JSON object:

```
package com.example.pokemon;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Poke_Info {
    private int albumId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String text;
    private String thumbnailUrl;

    public int getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl(){
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

#### The inteface is below: ###

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;


public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("photos") 
    Call<List<Poke_Info>> getPoke();
   }
```

#### The Adapter class along with ViewHolder:

```
package com.example.pokemon;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private List<Poke_Info> info;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(List<Poke_Info> info) {
        this.info = info;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder = new ExampleViewHolder(view);
        return exampleViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Poke_Info object = info.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(object.getThmbnailUrl()).into(holder.mImageView);
        holder.mTextView.setText(object.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            return info.size();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

#### The MainActivity :

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi;


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<Poke_Info> poke_infos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        jsonPlaceHolderApi=retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<List<Poke_Info>> call=jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPoke();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Poke_Info>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Poke_Info>> call, Response<List<Poke_Info>> response) {

                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Information").setMessage("Code: "+response.code()).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                    return;
                }

                poke_infos=response.body();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Poke_Info>> call, Throwable t) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Information").setMessage(t.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("OK", 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView=findViewById((R.id.recycler_view));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter=new ExampleAdapter(poke_infos);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

    }
```

#### Please tell if you wish to see some other code. Also ,the internet permisssion has been added in the Manifest file.

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you try hitting the API via some other tool to check if it is returning data?

Comment: And what is the complete API URL you are using?

Comment: The app isn't crashing. There aren't any errors but the RecyclerView is always empty when I open it.

Comment: @Smile. The API is returning data for sure 'cause first I displayed it in TextView, and then I wanted to display it in RecyclerView and that's when the problem came up. At first I was getting Null Pointer Exception 'cause the getItemCount() method returned 0 but then when I included a try-catch block, the app stopped crashing but recyclerView does not show the list. The complete API URL is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com is just an html page, are hitting some API like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 ?

Comment: @Smile jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/